# Do I need to use FileStream.Flush() or FileStream.Flush(true)?

Tags: c#, filestream, flush

In my program, I write a file, then call an external program that reads that file. Do I need [`Flush(true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474552(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure that the data is written entirely to disk, or is [`Flush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bw4h516(v=vs.110).aspx) sufficient?

```
class ExampleClass : IDisposable {
    private FileStream stream = File.Open("command-list.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);

    public void Execute(string command) {
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
        stream.WriteByte(10);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Flush(true);
        Process.Start("processor", "command-list.txt");
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Dispose`, or any kind of `Flush`, will make it so that other software will see the data that has been written, *but* it won't guarantee that the data will actually make it all the way to the disk.  If e.g. the data is being written to a USB drive and the cable gets unplugged before the data actually gets written, the program will only find out about the problem if uses a `Flush(true)` or other similar means to ensure that the data has been written before it it's finished.  Whether a program should use `Flush(true)` depends on the application.  If the hard drive is not removable and could only fail in cases where failure to write the file would be the least of one's problems, then `Flush(true)` is not necessary.  If a user might yank a USB drive as soon as the program thinks it's done, then `Flush(true)` may be a good idea.

Comment: I believe this is suitable for my purposes, as the external program copies the files externally, and does verify writes, and I only consider the action complete once that external program is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Neither; you should simply dispose the stream in a `using` statement.

Or, better yet, replace the whole thing with `File.AppendAllText()`.

Comment: That would make me open the stream and close it for every write, which is undesirable. I want to keep the file open, write to it often, and occasionally call the external processor.